# Is there a way to sort Ethereum GitHub committers by frequency their commits were merged?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Is there a way to sort Ethereum GitHub committers by percentage of the time their commits were ultimately merged?

By Ethereum I mean any of the Github repositories listed here https://github.com/ethereum such as:

- https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum
- https://github.com/ethereum/remix
- https://github.com/ethereum/solidity
- https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin
- https://github.com/ethereum/tests
- etc

Comment: I guess the experts are on stackoverflow. Besides that you are interested in the Ethereum repositories it has clearly nothing to do with Ethereum but all with Github...

Answer (score 1):

That would be a most or less pointless metric because every project has different commit and merge policies (e.g. go-ethereum squashes commits and requires a double review) and different people work on different areas with different complexity (e.g. fixing up minor patches will get you a ton of quick merges whereas major modifications will seam like you're slacking off).

Comment: You make a good point and I agree that it would not be a good metric to identify the "best" or most "competent" contributors for the reasons you identified. However maybe it would be helped to identify the worst (either because of extreme incompetence or intentionally malicious behavior). If someone made over 100 commits to an active repo and 0% of them were merged after sufficient time for review, would that not be a good indicator to be cautious in merging future commits from that person?